# Getting Same Firebase Notification multiple times

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I am using firebase to get notifications of subscribed topics. FirebaseMessagingService receives same notification multiple times. I have tried all of the provided solutions but nothing worked for me. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

**Module Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "abc.abc"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.5.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Project Gradle**

```
sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {

        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Manifest**

```
  <service android:name=".Firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".Firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

**FirebaseMessagingService**
This override function getting called multiple times despite of the fact that i am sending single notification.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        //Displaying data in log
        //It is optional
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG,refreshedToken);
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        //Calling method to generate notification
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

 private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.bazaar_noti_small)
                .setContentTitle("Price Updated")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: How many times your got Notification?

Comment: like 8 to 10 times.

Comment: what service you are using to send notification for Topic like Price Updated

Comment: @VineshChauhan i am sending notification from My server to firebase server to specific topic using curl. so that all devices subscribed to that topic get that notification.

Comment: did you fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show me your **sendNotification()** function.

Below code is my sample push notification. I

```
private void sendNotification(String title,String messageBody)
    {
        Intent viewIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(),
                0,
                viewIntent, // add this
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
                .setTicker("Test App")
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        //Random r = new Random();
        //int randomNumber = r.nextInt(100 - 0) + 0;

        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: I have updated my code block for you. now my sendNotification() is exposed. please have a look. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Second Parameter in

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(),
                0,
                viewIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

is known as request code need to be unique for each notification

refere https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Comment: Yes, I know that but that is only to show notification separately. Main issue for which i am worried is that why my onMessageReceived getting called multiple times?